# What is the correct word to use instead of else’s?

Tags: word-choice, possessives, is-it-a-word

If I am trying to say, “That problem that belongs to someone else,” then what is the correct word to use in this sentence:

> *That is someone else’s problem.*

My spell checker says *else’s* and *elses* are not words and does not have a correction suggestion for it. What is the correct word to use?

Comment: Just a FYI, the spell checker that is missing the word is the one included with Firefox 6.0.

Comment: Putt knot yore tryst inn spill chequers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would say, "That's an [SEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_Else%27s_Problem)". Anyone who knows me would know what I mean.

In any event *else's* is perfectly fine. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/else)'s entry for *else* says, "other or in addition (used in the possessive following an indefinite pronoun): *someone else's money*."

Comment: As an impecunious teenager, I always used to say my preferred cigarette brand was **SE**. By far the cheapest!

Comment: Nice reference to Douglas Adams.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with "someone else's".  Inexplicably, many spelling checkers don't automatically recognize possessives of user-added words, so don't try to read much out of that.

From a grammatical perspective, the key insight is that -'s is not a word clitic, it is a phrase clitic.  For example, it may be informal or even a little unidiomatic, but it is not ungrammatical to utter or write sentences like the following:

I take exception to the senator from Maryland's remarks.
The package that arrived on Monday's return address was somewhere in Texas.
The man I was talking to's attitude really bothered me.

Worrying about the placement of the possessive clitic is someone else's hang-up.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I usually deal in computer language grammar, and I wouldn't have had a word to express the 'clitic'.  Honestly, it would have been some time before I bumped into the "phrase clitic"... from a computer grammar perspective.  Thanks for the solid help.

Answer (score 0):

"Another's" I'd say. "Someone else's problem" is idiomatic and totally ok too.